# What is the difference between `fitclinear` and `fitcsvm`?

Tags: matlab, svm

In MATLAB the documentation says `fitclinear` uses SVM or logistic regression and `fitcsvm` also is an SVM.

Also `fitclinear` is usually faster. Why?

What is the difference between both?

Comment: At least one difference: Linear versus non linear support.

Comment: Linear support is offered by `fitcsvm` too. Why a separate `fitcilinear` then?

Comment: Because it may be more optimised as you stated in your question.

Comment: Okay, 'is that all' is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the description of [fitclinear](https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitclinear.html):

> For reduced computation time on a high-dimensional data set that
>   includes many predictor variables, train a linear classification model
>   by using fitclinear. For low- through medium-dimensional predictor
>   data sets, see Alternatives for Lower-Dimensional Data.

`fitcsvm` is present among these alternatives for Lower-Dimensional Data.

In other words, `fitclinear` is best to be used with high-dimensional data, while `fictsvm` should be used for low through medium-dimensional predictor data sets.